# Monitoring AWS Route53 health checks in other regions than us-east-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a health check configured to monitor us-west-2. I also want to setup an alarm for this healthcheck. However, I don't think this will work because the alarms for health checks must be in us-east-1, but the services themselves are in us-west-2.
I am using CloudFormation to define the stack. The issue is that you cannot reference the Healthcheck deployed while in us-west-2 when creating the alarm in us-east-1.

Here's a snippet of my alarm:

```
Alarm:
Condition: IsEast1AndMultiRegion
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
  ActionsEnabled: true
  AlarmActions:
    - !Ref AlarmTopic
  ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
  EvaluationPeriods: 1
  MetricName: HealthCheckPercentageHealthy
  Namespace: AWS/Route53
  AlarmDescription: "Alarm for Health Check"
  Period: 60
  Statistic: Maximum
  Threshold: 99
  TreatMissingData: notBreaching
  Dimensions:
    - Name: HealthCheckId
      Value: !GetAtt HealthCheckWithEndpoint.HealthCheckId
    - Name: Region
      Value: !FindInMap [ AccountSpecific, !Ref "AWS::AccountId", PrimaryRegion ]
```

Comment: " the alarms for health checks must be in us-east-1" - why do you think this is the case?

Comment: @jordanm because healthchecks are actually created in us-east-1 no matter where you deploy them.

Comment: @elena Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm currently facing a very similar situation.

Comment: @Fgop Nope, I just created the alarms manually instead in the AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

1 year later, but I found a workaround, assuming your health check is done the same way as mine - periodically invoking the /health endpoint (or equivalent).

The Route53 metric is not the only metric that is produced during the call. In my setup the request goes to API Gateway and that produces metrics as well. Specifically one for 5XX errors. Those are placed in respective regions.

Similarly, if you can look at metrics from Load Balancers if you have those or just produce a metric yourself with CloudWatch embedded logs or something.

I'm now building the alarm based on the 5XX metric from API Gateway